# Можно ли использовать виртуализацию для домашнего ПК?

Tags: linux, ос, hyper-v, kvm, xen

С темой не знаком, знаю только что на серверах используются гипервизоры (kvm и xen). Как я понял, они позволяют запустить одновременно несколько ОС и раскидать между ними ресурсы железа. Мне кажется это удобным для использования в домашнем ПК.

Почему мне это нужно?

Во-первых, мне хотелось бы отделить личную ОС от рабочей, т.к. рабочие дела, постоянно пересекаются с личными (браузеры, ПО, проекты, документы). На работе, например, часто бывает нужно шарить свой экран сотрудникам и постоянно думаешь о том, что не хотелось бы светить свои файлы (документы) и личные проекты (в т.ч. базы данных).

Во-вторых, работая в ОС для работы, хотелось бы слушать музыку и пользоваться личными аккаунтами (месенжерами, YouTube, Spotify) не логинясь под этим всем в рабочей ОС и не получать в ней же личные уведомления. К тому же не хотелось бы мешать конфиги git'а и ssh и других инструментов, которыми активно пользуюсь в личных и рабочих целях.

В-третьих, было бы не плохо на ряду с linux-ОС иметь запущеной Windows с какой нибудь игрушкой, которая будет молотить на фоне, а я бы периодически к на неё отвлекался и потом возвращался назад к работе. Это конечно блаж, но всё же. А может и какие-то нужные процессы появятся на Windows (например, бухгалтерия, с этими 1С, рутокенами и прочим б***ством).

Вопросов, на самом деле, оч много:

1. Можно ли установить такую виртуализацию для домашнего/рабочего ПК для одновременного запуска нескольких ОС и переключения между ними без перезагрузки ПК, как в случае с grub?
2. Можно ли будет комбинировать звук с нескольких ОС или, по крайней мере, в разных ОС использовать разные звуковые устройства одновременно?
3. Можно ли будет получить совместный доступ к микрофону, вебкамере, bluetooth, wifi и прочим интерфейсам?
4. Как будут шарится ресурсы видеокарты? Можно ли будет расчитывать на одновременное графическое ускорение в нескольких ОС (при отсутствии графики в ЦП)?
5. Как будет происходить управление этими гостевыми ОС? Можно ли поднять в хосте, что-то типа веб-сервера для управления через браузер из любой ОС? Или как это вообще происходит?
6. Чуть меньше чем пол жизни уже прожито. По этому, хотелось бы узнать, можно ли расчитывать, что, не потомственному админу оставшейся жизни хватит на то, чтобы разобраться со всеми этими делами, всё настроить и ещё и успеть по пользоваться этими благами?
7. Куда копать в первую очередь, что можно почитать и т.п.?
8. Реально ли вообще такое провернуть?
9. Как по-вашему, будет ли удобно этим пользоваться или для домашних целей такая виртуализация не подойдёт?

Comment: На всякий случай  добавлю сюда про установку kvm (правда увы на английском) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation в целом после установки у меня лучше стал работать VirtualBox и для Android Studio эмуляторов прироста не заметил.

Comment: Попробуйте VirtualBox

Comment: @Nick, да, как вариант. но к сожалению этот варинт не подходит по причине низкой производительности и стабильности работы. гостевая ОС работает значительно хуже хоста.

Answer (score 3):

Здраствуйте.
Как человек у которого уже чуть больше чем пол жизни уже прожито, попробую ответить.

- 8 Реально. — Но сильно дорого и очень замарочно. Я сам хотел сконструировать себе нечто подобное. Но в основном получается что не система для тебя. А ты для системы. На конструирование и администрирование всего этого уходит слишком много времени. Собственно для основной работы, которая тебя в общем и кормит остётся меньше сил. Это как-то не рациональнинько. Хотя это большой **experience**
- 9 В конечном счёте, если  сделать, это было бы удобно. Но повторюсь дорого и хлопотно. Не забывайте, что аппаратная часть т.е. железо должны быть очень мощные. Минимум двух процессорные Xeon'ы с много памяти и много SSD...
- 7 Для начала решите какая должна быть среда. Я бы смотрел в сторону аппаратной виртуализации. И начните тогда с этого выбора, через [вот эту хорошую табличку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD).
- 5 Это зависит от выбора виртуализации.
- 4 Про делегирование ресурсов видеокарты, написано не мало. К сожалению только на иностранном. Ну или я просто не находил на русском. И опять же. Видиокарта должна быть мощной. Ну или их должно быть несколько.
- 3 Про совместный доступ одновременно риалтайм, не слышал не разу.
- 2 По моему, опять же в риалтайм, это можно через внешний микшер. Ну или я не владею.

Ответ на 1 и 6 вопрос я думаю понятен из ответов на остальное. В комментариях в общем, на мой взгляд, правильный ответ уже есть. ***VirtualBox.*** В большинстве случаев, для домашних, а зачастую и для рабочих проектов хватает с головою.

И ещё ИМХО из личного опыта: Так вышло, и последние года 4 я в этом мнении закрепился, что гораздо удобнее иметь дома несколько машин. У меня линукс файловая помойка 10ТБ с  поднятым на ней Plex сервером для мультимедиа. Станция для оцифровки и вторых задач. И основной хеон для работы и игр. Ну ещё ноут на подхвате. Так получилось и дешевле и легче. Но решать конечно вам.

Всех благ.